# Failed to Connect to MySQL at localhost:3306 with user root Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I want to install MySQLWorkbench and when I setup new connection and test it, it shows me this error message
I tried all possible solutions and did not help.

[image]

any one can help me please :(

Comment: Error code 61 is a connection refused. Do you have a MySQL server running on your machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install a MySQL server locally as well, if you want to work with MySQL Workbench locally. You can download an installation package (e.g. for OSX) from here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/.

Once you have that server installed verify that it is running by e.g.:

```
ps aux | grep mysql
```

which will list all processes that have "mysql" in their command line (including the grep command itself). So, you should see at least one additional entry like this:

> root            10605   0,0  0,0  2448748    616   ??  S    21Jul16  0:00.02 /bin/sh /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data --pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/xxxxxxxx.pid